# PHP cURL to get dynamic content

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use cURL and PHP to scrape proxies off of a webpage. However, when I use cURL all I get is the CSS in the $content. The page uses wordpress so it dynamically loads content but I haven't found anything to help me download the dynamic content. I use wget in linux and the page downloads fine.

```
    <?php
//$source1 = file_get_contents('http://www.new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/');
$source1 = get_data("http://www.new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/");

$array = array();
$source1 = preg_grep('/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5}\b/', $array);





//download webpage
function get_data($url) {
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,     // return web page
            CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    // don't return headers
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
            CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13", // who am i
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 50,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
```

My output:

```
    (

string:203221) HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 22:09:23 GMT
Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 22:09:23 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 20:39:30 GMT
ETag: "c6675d47-80ec-48ee-9c0f-613c9419f172"
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 47132
Server: GSE

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html dir='ltr' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
<script type="text/javascript">(function() { var a=window,b="jstiming",d="tick";var e=function(c){this.t={};this.tick=function(c,p,h){h=void 0!=h?h:(new Date).getTime();this.t[c]=[h,p]};this[d]("start",null,c)},f=new e;a.jstiming={Timer:e,load:f};if(a.performance&&a.performance.timing){var g=a.performance.timing,j=a[b].load,k=g.navigationStart,l=g.responseStart;0<k&&l>=k&&(j[d]("_wtsrt",void 0,k),j[d]("wtsrt_","_wtsrt",l),j[d]("tbsd_","wtsrt_"))}
try{var m=null;a.chrome&&a.chrome.csi&&(m=Math.floor(a.chrome.csi().pageT),j&&0<k&&(j[d]("_tbnd",void 0,a.chrome.csi().startE),j[d]("tbnd_","_tbnd",k)));null==m&&a.gtbExternal&&(m=a.gtbExternal.pageT());null==m&&a.external&&(m=a.external.pageT,j&&0<k&&(j[d]("_tbnd",void 0,a.external.startE),j[d]("tbnd_","_tbnd",k)));m&&(a[b].pt=m)}catch(n){};a.tickAboveFold=function(c){var i=0;if(c.offsetParent){do i+=c.offsetTop;while(c=c.offsetParent)}c=i;750>=c&&a[b].load[d]("aft")};var q=!1;function r(){q||(q=!0,a[b].load[d]("firstScrollTime"))}a.addEventListener?a.addEventListener("scroll",r,!1):a.attachEvent("onscroll",r);
 })();</script>
<meta content='true' name='MSSmartTagsPreventParsing'/>
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
<link href='http://www.new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
<link href='http://new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/' rel='canonical'/>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="New Fresh Proxies - Atom" href="http://new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="New Fresh Proxies - RSS" href="http://new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" />
<link rel="service.post" type="application/atom+xml" title="New Fresh Proxies - Atom" href="http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2001908494944967755/posts/default" />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.blogger.com/rsd.g?blogID=2001908494944967755" />
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com/" />
<!--[if IE]> <script> (function() { var html5 = ("abbr,article,aside,audio,canvas,datalist,details," + "figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output," + "progress,section,time,video").split(','); for (var i = 0; i < html5.length; i++) { document.createElement(html5[i]); } try { document.execCommand('BackgroundImageCache', false, true); } catch(e) {} })(); </script> <![endif]-->
<title>New Fresh Proxies</title>
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='//www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/3950009988-widget_css_bundle.css' />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=2001908494944967755&zx=c6675d47-80ec-48ee-9c0f-613c9419f172"/>
<style id='page-skin-1' type='text/css'><!--
/*
-----------------------------------------------
Theme Name: Harmonika
Theme URL: http://newwpthemes.com/wordpress-theme/harmonika/
Description: Harmonika is a free WordPress theme with options page and supports the post thumbnails. Suitable for any niche.
Author: NewWpThemes.com
Author URI: http://newwpthemes.com/
Version: 1.0
Tags: Ads Ready, Two Columns, Right Sidebar, Fixed Width, Blogging, Options Page
Template Name: Harmonika
Template URI: http://themecraft.net/2010/06/harmonika-blogger-template
Version: 1.0
Author: Theme Craft
Author URI: http://www.themecraft.net
Harmonika Blogger Template comes under a Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 2.5 Malaysia License.
This means it is free to use on your blog, and you must keep the footer link intact, also as a respect to the designer and converter.
We sincerely need your respect to continue our free Blogger template production, thank you.
ThemeCraft.net
----------------------------------------------- */
/* Use this with templates/template-twocol.html */
#navbar-iframe{
height:0px;
visibility:hidden;
display:none;
}
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------
Blueprint CSS Framework 0.8
http://blueprintcss.org
* Copyright (c) 2007-Present. See LICENSE for more info.
* See README for instructions on how to use Blueprint.
* For credits and origins, see AUTHORS.
* This is a compressed file. See the sources in the 'src' directory.
----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* reset.css */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-weight:inherit;font-style:inherit;font-size:100%;font-family:inherit;}
body {line-height:1.5;}
caption, th, td {text-align:left;font-weight:normal;}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content:"";}
blockquote, q {quotes:"" "";}
img {max-width: 100%; /* not working in IE6*/}
a img {max-width: 100%; /* not working in IE6*/ border:none;}
/* typography.css */
body {font-size:75%;color:#222;background:#000;font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-weight:normal;}
h1 {font-size:3em;line-height:1;margin-bottom:0.5em;}
h2 {font-size:2em;margin-bottom:0.75em;}
h3 {font-size:1.5em;line-height:1;margin-bottom:1em;}
h4 {font-size:1.2em;line-height:1.25;margin-bottom:1.25em;}
h5 {font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:1.5em;}
h6 {font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;}
h1 img, h2 img, h3 img, h4 img, h5 img, h6 img {margin:0;}
p {margin:0 0 1.5em;}
p img.left {float:left;margin:1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 0;padding:0;}
p img.right {float:right;margin:1.5em 0 1.5em 1.5em;}
a:focus, a:hover {color:#000;}
a {color:#009;text-decoration:underline;}
blockquote {margin:1.5em;color:#666;font-style:italic;}
strong {font-weight:bold;}
em, dfn {font-style:italic;}
dfn {font-weight:bold;}
sup, sub {line-height:0;}
abbr, acronym {border-bottom:1px dotted #666;}
address {margin:0 0 1.5em;font-style:italic;}
del {color:#666;}
pre {margin:1.5em 0;white-space:pre;}
pre, code, tt {font:1em 'andale mono', 'lucida console', monospace;line-height:1.5;}
li ul, li ol {margin:0 1.5em;}
ul, ol {margin:0 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;}
ul {list-style-type:disc;}
ol {list-style-type:decimal;}
dl {margin:0 0 1.5em 0;}
dl dt {font-weight:bold;}
dd {margin-left:1.5em;}
table {margin-bottom:1.4em;width:100%;}
th {font-weight:bold;}
thead th {background:#c3d9ff;}
tr.even td {background:#e5ecf9;}
tfoot {font-style:italic;}
caption {background:#eee;}
.small {font-size:.8em;margin-bottom:1.875em;line-height:1.875em;}
.large {font-size:1.2em;line-height:2.5em;margin-bottom:1.25em;}
.hide {display:none;}
.quiet {color:#666;}
.loud {color:#000;}
.highlight {background:#ff0;}
.added {background:#060;color:#fff;}
.removed {background:#900;color:#fff;}
.first {margin-left:0;padding-left:0;}
.last {margin-right:0;padding-right:0;}
.top {margin-top:0;padding-top:0;}
.bottom {margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;}
/* forms.css */
label {font-weight:bold;}
fieldset {padding:1.4em;margin:0 0 1.5em 0;border:1px solid #ccc;}
legend {font-weight:bold;font-size:1.2em;}
input.text, input.title, textarea, select {margin:0.5em 0;border:1px solid #bbb;}
input.text:focus, input.title:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {border:1px solid #666;}
input.text, input.title {width:300px;padding:5px;}
input.title {font-size:1.5em;}
textarea {width:390px;height:250px;padding:5px;}
.error, .notice, .success {padding:.8em;margin-bottom:1em;border:2px solid #ddd;}
.error {background:#FBE3E4;color:#8a1f11;border-color:#FBC2C4;}
.notice {background:#FFF6BF;color:#514721;border-color:#FFD324;}
.success {background:#E6EFC2;color:#264409;border-color:#C6D880;}
.error a {color:#8a1f11;}
.notice a {color:#514721;}
.success a {color:#264409;}
/* grid.css */
.container {width:950px;margin:0 auto;}
.showgrid {background:url(src/grid.png);}
.column, div.span-1, div.span-2, div.span-3, div.span-4, div.span-5, div.span-6, div.span-7, div.span-8, div.span-9, div.span-10, div.span-11, div.span-12, div.span-13, div.span-14, div.span-15, div.span-16, div.span-17, div.span-18, div.span-19, div.span-20, div.span-21, div.span-22, div.span-23, div.span-24 {float:left;margin-right:10px;}
.last, div.last {margin-right:0;}
.span-1 {width:30px;}
.span-2 {width:70px;}
.span-3 {width:110px;}
.span-4 {width:150px;}
.span-5 {width:190px;}
.span-6 {width:230px;}
.span-7 {width:270px;}
.span-8 {width:310px;}
.span-9 {width:350px;}
.span-10 {width:390px;}
.span-11 {width:430px;}
.span-12 {width:470px;}
.span-13 {width:510px;}
.span-14 {width:550px;}
.span-15 {width:590px;}
.span-16 {width:630px;}
.span-17 {width:670px;}
.span-18 {width:710px;}
.span-19 {width:750px;}
.span-20 {width:790px;}
.span-21 {width:830px;}
.span-22 {width:870px;}
.span-23 {width:910px;}
.span-24, div.span-24 {width:950px;margin:0;}
input.span-1, textarea.span-1, input.span-2, textarea.span-2, input.span-3, textarea.span-3, input.span-4, textarea.span-4, input.span-5, textarea.span-5, input.span-6, textarea.span-6, input.span-7, textarea.span-7, input.span-8, textarea.span-8, input.span-9, textarea.span-9, input.span-10, textarea.span-10, input.span-11, te...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like either a timeout or a problem with your Regexp.

Why not stick to `file_get_contents` like you tried in the first place?

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.new-fresh-proxies.blogspot.com.au');

preg_match_all('/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(:\d+)?)/', $content, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

This will print out a list of IPs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.204.168.15:6673
    [1] => 1.234.45.130:80
    [2] => 1.34.163.101:8080
    [3] => 1.34.29.89:8080
    [4] => 1.34.8.221:3128
    ....
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Curl wont be able to get it directly since it wont execute javascript. But if its coming from an ajax request, you can make a request to that endpoint directly.

Use dev tools/firebug to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

- Where is your 'output' coming from? I see no displays in your code ...
- I also think your `preg_grep` statement is incorrect. You're searching a blank array and saving the result to the variable you just pulled your data into. Try:

`$array = preg_grep('/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{1,5}\b/', $source1);`

When I run the code and dump `$source1['content']` directly after the `get_data` call, I get a crap-ton of IP addresses ...

Comment: $content = curl_exec( $ch );

Comment: But in your function, you were assigning `$header['content'] = $content;` and returning `$header` ... so, the content would have been in `$source1['content']` ... either way, glad you got it figured out ...